# Firefox UI API - Extension only working with Cfx Run

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

While playing arround with the new UI Api (specifically Action Button) from the new Firefox Addon SDK i stepped into a bug/problem. I know its currently experimental and the new APIs only work with the currenty Nightly V30 of Firefox but maybe someone has a suggestion how to make it work.

I want to create a simple Extension that adds a Button to the Toolbar on the right side of the search field. Everything is working fine when I use "cfx run" to test my extension, but as soon as I create the XPI with "cfx xpi" and try to install it into Nightly the Button doesn't appear. The Installation process seems fine and the addons appears in the addon section of firefox but not the button.

My Code for the Extension:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var base64 = require("sdk/base64");
var ui = require("sdk/ui");

var action_button = ui.ActionButton({
    id: "My Extension",
    label: "Extension Description",
    icon: {
        "16": "./logo-grey-16.png",
        "32": "./logo-grey-32.png",
        "64": "./logo-grey-64.png",
        "128": "./logo-grey-128.png",
    },
    onClick: function() {
        url = base64.encode(tabs.activeTab.url);
        tabs.open("http://example.com/r/" + url);
    }
});
```

Comment: I would guess it's a bug in the nightly. Aurora's already on 30. Have you tested it with that?

Comment: Also, the [Add-on SDK 1.16 was just released](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/03/27/announcing-add-on-sdk-1-16). Maybe try with that.